# How to prevent laravel jetstream modal to close when clicking on the background?

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-livewire, alpine.js, laravel-jetstream

I would like to make the `jetstream modal static` .. dismiss only if the click is done via the cancel button.

---

In bootstrap I could do this

```
$('#myModal').modal({
backdrop: 'static',
keyboard: false
})
```

Comment: For these sort of questions it's generally expected to also provide a basic code block that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I have found was to remove the `x-on:click` event in  the modal component after publishing jetstream components.

change this

```
<div x-show="show" class="fixed inset-0 transform transition-all" x-on:click="show = false" x-transition:enter="ease-out duration-300"
                    x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0"
                    x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100"
                    x-transition:leave="ease-in duration-200"
                    x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
                    x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0">
        <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-500 opacity-75"></div>
    </div>
```

to

```
<div x-show="show" class="fixed inset-0 transform transition-all"  x-transition:enter="ease-out duration-300"
                    x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0"
                    x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100"
                    x-transition:leave="ease-in duration-200"
                    x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
                    x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0">
        <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-500 opacity-75"></div>
    </div>
```